# I cannot see the change in PersonDetail.jsx page. It is always printing "Loading Details..."

Tags: reactjs

When a state changes in React, the component that has the specific state will trigger a re-render, causing all of its descendants to also re-render. This is the only condition to trigger a re-render. In this code, the isLoading is being set as "false" in Home.jsx. However, it is located in App.jsx, so when this state changes, the App component, as well as its children, will be re-rendered. But when I refresh the PersonDetail.jsx page, nothing is changing. I am taking a look at the React Dev Tools and isLoading is always "true", this issue is getting solved when I do the setIsLoading operation directly in App.jsx, but I still wanted to understand the logic. Why is it not changing in PersonDetail.jsx? I'll be so glad if someone can help me.

## App Component

```
    import { Outlet, RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import PersonDetail from "./pages/PersonDetail";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([{ id: 1, name: "john doe" }]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  return (
    <RouterProvider
      router={createBrowserRouter([
        {
          path: "/",
          element: (
            <div>
              <Outlet />
            </div>
          ),
          children: [
            {
              index: true,
              element: (
                <Home
                  isLoading={isLoading}
                  setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
                  people={people}
                />
              ),
            },
            {
              path: "/people/:personId",
              element: <PersonDetail isLoading={isLoading} people={people} />,
            },
          ],
        },
      ])}
    />
  );
};`
```

export default App;

## Home Page#

```
    import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = ({ people, isLoading, setIsLoading }) => {
  console.log(isLoading);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading data...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      {people.map((person) => {
        return (
          <Link key={person.id} to={`/people/${person.id}`}>
            <h3>{person.name}</h3>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

## PersonDetail Page#

```
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const PersonDetail = ({ isLoading, people }) => {

  const { personId } = useParams();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading Details...</h1>;
  }

  const person = people.find((person) => person.id == personId);

  const { name } = person;

  return <div>Name: {name}</div>;
};

export default PersonDetail;
```

English in not my native language. I am sorry if my question was not quite easy to understand.